# Axis Web Service throws error: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method

Tags: java, linux, apache-axis

I am trying to invoke a web service that I have just hosted on out linux redhat server but it throws the error {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method + "methodname"
I host the service in apache tomcat webserver

The same service works fine when i host it in the windows xp environment with the same apache web server...

Is there anyone who has experienced a similar problem.

thanks..

Comment: You should also give the Axis and tomcat version

Answer (score 1):

in the axis2.xml ...

```
<parameter name="sendStacktraceDetailsWithFaults">false</parameter>
```

set the sendStacktraceDetailsWithFaults parameter to true and you should get a copy of the stacktrace in the response (reset to false for production)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something similar. Our dev environment was running JBoss and Ubuntu, and prod/test was running Red Hat, Apache in front and JBoss.

Prod/test was running https with certificates, and our problem was that our certificates where out of date. When we fixed that, the webservice calls got through.
Maybe thats your problem?

Another thing you should do to debug is see if the wsdl is deployed and check what the webservice address it is deployed under. Maybe the address is very different in prod?

For instance in JBoss if you go to

```
http://localhost:8080/jbossws/services
```

you will see all the services that are deployed and what url they have.

Comment: the service address is actually correct however I have noted that the failure is at the encoding level "at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)"

Comment: Hmm haven't encountered that exception. You should provide more information, like Stacktrace and like @araviski says, Axis and tomcat version if that is applicable.